# How to connect several points from a fix point - R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to connect a paired data always from a fix point (**P2** in the data below). I have tried to use ggplot, but it appears to many lines.
From the following data example:

```
A <-c(rep("A",4))
B <-c(rep("B",5))
X1<-c(-1,5,3,6)
X2<-c(5,0,2,9,3)
Y1<-c(1,-5,0,4)
Y2<-c(-6,0,1,9,-4)

df <- data.frame (Field = c(A,B),
      Point = c("P1","P2","P3","P4","P1","P2","P3","P4","P5"),
      X= c(X1,X2),
      Y= c(Y1,Y2))
```

I would like to obtain the following plot as exemplified for **Field A** (*keeping point **P2** as the staring value*)

```
output <- data.frame ( Link =c("AP2-AP1","AP2-AP1","AP2-AP3","AP2-AP3","AP2-AP4","AP2-AP4"),
      X=c(5,-1,5,3,5,6),
      Y=c(-5,1,-5,0,-5,4))
```

Pretended plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(output,aes(x=X, y=Y, group=Link)) +
geom_line()+ geom_point()+
theme_bw(base_size = 20)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `geom_segment`. Then you need a data set with starting points (`x`, `y`) and end points (`xend`, `yend`) on each line.

This can be acheived by joining data *with* the "P2" points, with data *without* the "P2" points, within each "Field" (`df[Point == "P2"][df[Point != "P2"], on = "Field"]`). Here I use the `data.table` package for the join, but it can be done in several different ways.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
ggplot(data = df, aes(X, Y, color = Field)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = df[Point == "P2"][df[Point != "P2"], on = "Field"],
               aes(xend = i.X, yend = i.Y))
```

[image]

P.S. I added `color = Field` just to make it easier to distinguish the two groups in this example.

Comment: Sorry, but the following error appeared: _Error in `[.data.frame`(df, Point == "P2") : object 'Point' not found_

Nonetheless, is precisely this plot I was thinking

Comment: Excellent, it works perfectly :) just a note. in color brackets must be removed ,ie.: `ggplot(data = df, aes(X, Y, color = Field))`

Comment: could you further help me with setting a color (or Linetype) for according to the line slope? Or is it better to set a new question?